# How can I query complex nested JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json

I have the below JSON data which is a shortened version of AWS "cli describe ec2 data" output.

I need to use Python so that I can query an InstanceId value and get all of of its VolumeId values (there may be more than 1 entry) and its PrivateIpAddress value.

The output would look something like this:

```
   i-01,10.1.1.1,vol-123,vol-456
   i-02,10.2.2.2,vol-789
```

I am new to Python and cant seem to find the answer on how to do this. Can anyone help?

```
{
"Reservations": [
    {
        "Instances": [
            {
                "InstanceId": "i-01",
                "PrivateIpAddress": "10.1.1.1", 
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                     {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda", 
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Status": "attached", 
                            "VolumeId": "vol-123", 
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sdb", 
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Status": "attached", 
                            "VolumeId": "vol-456", 
                        }
                    }
                ], 
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Value": "Server01", 
                        "Key": "Name"
                    }
                ], 
                "AmiLaunchIndex": 0
            }
        ], 
        "OwnerId": "123456789"
    }, 
    {
        "Instances": [
            {
                "InstanceId": "i-02",
                "PrivateIpAddress": "10.2.2.2", 
                "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                     {
                        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda", 
                        "Ebs": {
                            "Status": "attached", 
                            "VolumeId": "vol-789", 
                        }
                    }
                ], 
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "Value": "Server02", 
                        "Key": "Name"
                    }
                ], 
                "AmiLaunchIndex": 0
            }
        ], 
        "OwnerId": "123456789"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = []
for reservation in d["Reservations"]:
    res = {}
    instances = reservation["Instances"][0]
    res['InstanceID'] = instances['InstanceId']
    res['PrivateIpAddress'] = instances['PrivateIpAddress']
    res['BlockDeviceMappings'] = []
    for blockdevice in instances['BlockDeviceMappings']:
        res['BlockDeviceMappings'].append(blockdevice['Ebs']['VolumeId'])
    result.append(res)
```

You can then do:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

to have the results displayed in a nice way.